# Does deleting a table delete its triggers as well as functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-9.6

I have created a table `score` and also created a function and a trigger along with it.

```
CREATE TABLE scores( 
--fields
);

CREATE FUNCTION scores_before_save() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
   -- function logic
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER scores_before_save BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON scores
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE scores_before_save();
```

Now, I dropped this table

```
DROP TABLE scores;
```

So my question is that are triggers and functions automatically deleted once we delete the table or we need to manually delete them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily check them

```
-- check function existence
SELECT proname  FROM pg_proc WHERE proname    = 'scores_before_save';

-- check trigger existence
SELECT trigger_name from information_schema.triggers 
where trigger_name = 'scores_before_save';
```

as you can see, after drop table, function stays here, but trigger is removed.